# "No feature was found..." when making custom grid coordinate format

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules, qgsexpression

I'm in QGIS layouts trying to make a custom grid coordinate format but get the error:

> No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.

This error does not appear if I have a single `substr()` function but when I add a second it errors.

```
concat(substr(@grid_number, -5, 2),
       ",",
       substr(@grid_number, -3)
       )
```

[image]

Comment: OP should add information about what is the aim of the expression and what the variable `@grid_number` represents.

Comment: @Babel `@grid_number` is a built in expression in printlayout representing the current lat/lon value of the added grid.

Comment: @MrXsquared - OK, I see, a context variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your double quotes of `","` into single quotes `','`, since it is not related to a fieldname but is meant to represent a string value:

```
concat(substr(@grid_number, -5, 2),
       ',',
       substr(@grid_number, -3)
       )
```

The error `No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.` is caused by QGIS trying to lookup for a field named `,` but there is no feature which this expression is evaluated against and therefore also no fieldname named like that.

Comment: Thank you. No matter the programming language I always get confused about double and single quotes. Wish QGIS had better docs for their language.